# How to set column to the Excel file generated in Python?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

This is the project to compare two excel sheets and generate another excel file called Excel_diff.xlsx to show the difference.

I have written the following script and I wish to set the width of Column A to 30 using a function called `properties()`.

The code can be compiled without any error. However, the output Excel_diff.xlsx does not have the width of 30 in Column A. May I ask which part of my script is written wrongly and how to change it to achieve the objective?

My approach is to use `worksheet.set_column(1,1,30)` to set the width of starting and ending of the column desired (column A) to 30.

Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter as xw

def comparison():
    df1=pd.read_excel('Testing.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
    df2=pd.read_excel('Testing.xlsx', 'Sheet2')

    comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
    rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)

    for item in zip(rows,cols):   
        df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]],df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])

    df1.to_excel('./Excel_diff.xlsx',index=False,header=True)

def properties():
    workbook=xw.Workbook('./Excel_diff.xlsx')
    worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.set_column(1,1,30)

properties()
comparison()
```

Comment: XlsxWriter can’t read or modify existing files. See also: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Comment: @jmcnamara Any solution to adjust the width using Python?